# Android - Change Activity content to more than 1 fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

help me bro,
this is my activity class

```
public class menuJadwalUjian extends AppCompatActivity{
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private Context mContex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_jadwal_ujian);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentJadwalUjian, new fragment_jadwal_ujian_menu()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

}
public void onClick(View v){

}
```

and this is the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_menu_ujian"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="xyz.aufa.asistenkuliahku.ActivityClass.menuJadwalUjian">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="IKI MAIN E OJO SAMPEK KETOK"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentJadwalUjian"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

this is my first Fragment Class

```
public class fragment_jadwal_ujian_menu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jadwal_ujian_menu, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initView(view);
}
private void changeFragment(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_menu_ujian, new fragment_jadwal_ujian_form()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
private void initView(View view){
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddJadwalUjian);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fabAddJadwalUjian:
            changeFragment();
            break;
    }
}
```

this is the layout for first layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="xyz.aufa.asistenkuliahku.fragment_jadwal_ujian_menu">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MENU NYA DI SINI GAN"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/fabAddJadwalUjian"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plusone_standard_off_client"/>
```

the goal is, how to make the activity always use first fragment, and replace the activity layout, and when i press back button, the activity is still show, and fragment is gone.
but i have problem why when i launch the activity, activity content is doesnt replace with fragment, and always stack like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tObk6.jpg)

the previous problem is, when i finally launch activity with the fragment, but the tool bar is gone.

i wont use view pager, because i wont to swipe and change my fragment.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Replace you xml code with below code.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#FFFFFF"
 tools:context="xyz.aufa.asistenkuliahku.fragment_jadwal_ujian_menu">
 <EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="MENU NYA DI SINI GAN"/>
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
android:id="@+id/fabAddJadwalUjian"
android:src="@drawable/ic_plusone_standard_off_client"/>
```

Comment: if i just change my background, i still got my activity layout, when i press back button. how can i truly change my activity with fragment